# How to replace the backflow prevent valve without risking to drain the boiler

Tags: plumbing

How to replace the 9d backflow prevent valve on my boiler without risking to drain the boiler? Does PRV works as check valve in this case? Is there any risk the water flow from PRV during the replacement?How can I  prevent that??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how this site works with upvotes for helpful information. By boiler are you referring to your hot water tank? If so, why are you concerned about draining it?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about my Hot water gas boiler.

Comment: What make/model of boiler do you have? What's a "9d backflow prevent valve"? Adding a picture or two would also help.

Comment: Boilers should be drained periodically to extend their life. Any particular reason not to drain it? You can shut it down and isolate it with the shutoff valves.

Comment: PRVs or pressure regulating valves aren't flow preventers - they are flow restrictors.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace the backflow preventer without draining your hot water heater. Water heaters have isolation valves that you can close after you shut down the the HW heater. However, unless you have isolation valves (shutoffs) for the backflow preventer you will probably still have to shut off your water at the main. The PRV will not prevent water flow when you remove the 9D backflow preventer. PRVs are flow restrictors not flow preventers.
As I mentioned in my comments - hot water heaters should be drained periodically - maybe annually - to extend their life by removing sediment from the tank. This may be a good time to do it.